# SQL Server 2012 Remote Access Outside Domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an SQL Server 2012 instance installed on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

I configured SQL Server for remote access.

I need to access the SQL Server from a machine which is not on the same domain as the SQL Server instance using JDBC. I get the following error

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
>   with Windows authentication.

I simply need the ability to access the SQL Server from various machines which will not (and never) be part of the same domain as the sql server instance.

Solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad question since there are so many factors that can prevent access to your SQL Server. Here are some general tips:

1. Enable access to certain protocols (TCP/IP, Named Pipes, etc.) via [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) on the db server.
2. Enable access to port 1433 (the port used by SQL Server) on the db server [via Windows Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx) *and* any network-level firewalls.
3. If using a Windows user to log in to the SQL Server then make sure this user (or one of the groups to which it belongs) is [mapped to a SQL Server login](http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=41).

Comment: thanks Keith. The mapping of windows account to SQL Server login worked nicely. I also tried connecting with IntergratedSecurity=false in the JDBC connection string and it also worked.